# Pythonic way for recursive reduction in python

Tags: python, reduce

While reducing a list in python, I have thought about creating a multiple list reduction and wrote the following snippet.

```
def multiply(a, b): return a * b

def recursive_reduce(reduce_func, *args):
     ret_val = reduce(reduce_func, *args)
     if type(ret_val) == list:
         ret_val = recursive_reduce(reduce_func, ret_val)
     return ret_val

a = [1, 1, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

recursive_reduce(multiply, a, b)
```

This works. However I would like to know whether defining the logic for iteration based on the type of the return value is pythonic or not.

Do we have any other way which accomplishes recursive reduction in more elegant way?

Comment: Is this python2? What is `reduce` in the first line of your function? `functools.reduce`?

Comment: Yes, this is python2 code. The reduce function is available without any imports. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: It's definitely not pythonic.  It's not even sensible.  The reduce function returns a single value.  The if statement is taken only when `reduce_func` somehow combines two lists into one.  But you call recursive_reduce from main with three arguments (a function and two lists).  The recursive call has only two arguments, a function and one list.  So how is the same function supposed to handle two cases?

Comment: Why do you need to call your reduction function multiple times? Why doesn't it always reduce the number of dimensions of the iterable it's being called on? From my POV it looks like there's a problem with your reduction function you should fix instead of calling it from a recursive function.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, the if statement evaluates to True in the above example. Regarding this not being pythonic way, may be and thats why I asked this question and want to learn more about it.

Comment: I saw that and I edited my comment.

Comment: The first time you call reduce, the array b is an initializer and a is the values to be iterated through.  In the function multiply, x will be a list and y will be an integer; so x * y is a new list consisting of y copies of the original list x.  The `*` operator performs list duplication.  The second time you call reduce, you have only one argument so you get the product of all the elements of the list.  The `*` operator now performs multiplication.  The program will run and give you an output, but mathematically it makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you're trying to do is do a recursive version of reduce.

```
def rreduce(f, init, default=None):                     
    if default is None:
        default = init[0]
        init = init[1:]
    if len(init) == 0:
         return default
    return rreduce(f, init[1:], f(default, init[0]))


>>> rreduce(lambda a, b: a*b, range(1,10))
362880
>>> rreduce(lambda a, b: a+b, ['t', 'a', 'c', 'o'])
'taco'
```

While recursion is great, this is not the preferred way in Python for `reduce` type functions because it is slow and you will hit a **STACK OVERFLOW** (HAA)

```
>>> rreduce(lambda a, b: a + [b], list(range(1, 10000)), [])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-7dc07c5d9246> in <module>()
----> 1 rreduce(lambda a, b: a + [b], list(range(1, 10000)), [])

<ipython-input-33-37206eb8e39f> in rreduce(f, init, default)
      5     if len(init) == 0:
      6         return default
----> 7     return rreduce(f, init[1:], f(default, init[0]))

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-33-37206eb8e39f> in rreduce(f, init, default)
      5     if len(init) == 0:
      6         return default
----> 7     return rreduce(f, init[1:], f(default, init[0]))

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

To answer your ACTUAL question...

```
def lreduce(f, init, default=None):
        if default is None:
            return reduce(lambda x, a: x + [reduce(f, a)], init, [])
        else:
            return reduce(lambda x, a: x + [reduce(f, a, default)], init, [])
```

will `reduce` a list of lists.

```
>>> lreduce(lambda a, b: a + b, [range(10), range(10), range(10)])
[45, 45, 45]
```

The reason the `if/else` is necessary is because `reduce` as a `builtin` does not accept keyword arguments:

```
In [56]: reduce(function=lambda a, b: a + b, sequence=range(10), initial=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-9fa3ed177831> in <module>()
----> 1 reduce(function=lambda a, b: a + b, sequence=range(10), initial=0)

TypeError: reduce() takes no keyword arguments
```

and then if you wanted to do one step further...

```
def lreduceall(f, init, default=None):
    if default is None:
        return reduce(f, reduce(lambda x, a: x + [reduce(f, a)], init, []))
    else:
        return reduce(f, reduce(lambda x, a: x + [reduce(f, a, default)], init, []), default)
```

finally:

```
>>> lreduceall(lambda a, b: a + b, [range(10), range(10), range(10)])
135
```

Comment: I got to answer a question about a stack overflow on stack overflow.  This is the greatest day of my life.

Comment: Thanks. I have got clarity from your idea now. I will try this approach.

Comment: great!  Don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer so you can help others in the future!